# How can I extract characters from one column and add it into another existing column in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, extract, columnsorting

I would like to extract information from one column and substitute it in another existing column. So this is what happened. I have a variable that identifies country_year, that I divided into two columns, country and year. So, just for example:

```
id           Country    year   
AUS_1999     AUS        1999    
CAN_1999     CAN        1999    
AUS_2000     AUS        2000     
CAN_2000     CAN        2000    
BELS1999     BELS1999   NA
```

In the example, notice that the fifth observation was not separated by an "_", because the code that I used to separate the id column. It ended up with a missing value in the year column and the country column is also wrong. There are a few of these observations in my data frame. How can I correct it for all these observations, by extracting information from the id column and adding to existing columns that I already created (country and year)?

I tried to be as clear as possible, let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Is the year always 4 digits at the end? If so it would be easy to split off that.

Comment: Yes, years are always 4 digits. However, country code is not always 3 digits as the example shows. And not always separated by a "_". How would you slip it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use a regex lookaround to `separate` the column 'id'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   separate(id, into = c("Country", "year"), 
       sep = "_|(?<=[A-Z])(?=\\d)", remove = FALSE)
```

-output

```
        id Country year
1 AUS_1999     AUS 1999
2 CAN_1999     CAN 1999
3 AUS_2000     AUS 2000
4 CAN_2000     CAN 2000
5 BELS1999    BELS 1999
```

---

Or with `extract`

```
df1 %>% 
  extract(id, into = c("Country", "year"), "^([A-Z]+)_?(\\d+)", remove = FALSE)
        id Country year
1 AUS_1999     AUS 1999
2 CAN_1999     CAN 1999
3 AUS_2000     AUS 2000
4 CAN_2000     CAN 2000
5 BELS1999    BELS 1999
```

---

Or in `base R`, insert a `_` where there are none between the uppercase letter and a digit to read it with `read.table` into two columns

```
cbind(df1, read.table(text = sub("([A-Z])(\\d)", "\\1_\\2", df1$id), 
   header = FALSE, sep = "_", col.names = c("Country", "year")))
```

-output

```
        id Country year
1 AUS_1999     AUS 1999
2 CAN_1999     CAN 1999
3 AUS_2000     AUS 2000
4 CAN_2000     CAN 2000
5 BELS1999    BELS 1999
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c("AUS_1999", "CAN_1999", "AUS_2000", "CAN_2000", 
"BELS1999")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Wow, so many different ways. I hope this helps more people too.

Comment: @VictorShin, akrun is not man, he is a R-superman :) :). He helped me a lot, when I was learning R.

Comment: @Neeraj lol Akrun sure did save my day, so yeah I agree! He is a super man! :)

Comment: What does the `"^([A-Z]+)_?(\\d+)"` quote do here?

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand it captures (`(...)`) the one or more (`+`) upper case letters `[A-Z]`), followed by any `_`, and then capture the digits (`\\d+`) that follows

Comment: Thanks @akrun that is helpful to know. I feel like commands in `dplyr` are easy enough to pick up but the super useful details like this are lost to me.

Comment: On the same tune, can you explain what "_|(?<=[A-Z])(?=\\d)" means too?

Comment: @VictorShin it is a regex lookaround (`(?<=`), which implies that look for the junction between an upper case letter (`[A-Z]`) and a digit (`\\d`) as there was no separation.  But, there was also some cases with `_`, so, we use OR (`|`) an underscore (`_`)